# Ejecutar un formulario luego de este código

Tags: c#

Tengo este código que mata todos los procesos que empiecen con un nombre, lo que quiero es que después de matar un proceso, muestre un formulario o haga goto a otra parte del código

```
Process.GetProcesses()
.Where(x => x.ProcessName.StartsWith("example", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
.ToList()
.ForEach(x => x.Kill());
```

Comment: y cual seria el problema?

Comment: ese código que tiene que ver con el código que muestras?

Comment: Pues si, la pregunta es facil, ejecutar ese codigo y si el proceso fue matado , mostrar un formulario o hacer goto a otra parte del codigo

Comment: si, se puede.. pero cual es la pregunta? para mostrar un formulario, lo inicializas y lo muestras...

Comment: lo que quiero es que despues de matar un proceso (osea si se ejecuto exitosamente el comando), haga goto a otra parte del codigo , eso nomas , como se hace es la pregunta

Comment: pues llamas a esa parte del codigo.. llamas a la funcion o a lo que sea.. no es clara tu pregunta... es mas, si quisieras hacer un goto, haces un [goto](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/jump-statements#the-goto-statement)

Comment: a ver, yo quiero ejecutar el siguiente codigo que es Process.GetProcesses()
.Where(x => x.ProcessName.StartsWith("example", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
.ToList()
.ForEach(x => x.Kill());

Comment: si el codigo mato algun proceso, quiero que haga un goto a otra parte del codigo, si no mato a ningun proceso , no quiero que haga nada , esa es la pregunta

Comment: Todo esto y más lo puedes explicar / aclarar / ampliar si vas a [edit] tu pregunta. Acá en los comentarios eso se pierde.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código podría quedar así:

```
Process.GetProcesses().
Where(x => x.ProcessName.StartsWith("example", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).
ToList().
ForEach(x => {
              x.Kill();
              //Otras instrucciones;
             });
```

Dentro de tu **metodo Foreach** abrirías llave y pondrías allí todas las instrucciones que desees, finalmente cerrarías llave.

Otra forma de hacerlo podria ser:

```
var procesos = Process.GetProcesses().
Where(x => x.ProcessName.StartsWith("example", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).
ToList().

foreach (var p in procesos)
{
   p.Kill();
   //Otras instrucciones;
}
```

Guardarías en una lista todos los procesos y después harías un **foreach** que matara al proceso y ejecutara otras instrucciones.

Comment: yo no se.. como entendiste la pregunta.. que para mi, sigue siendo totalmente confusa.. porque siempre habla de ir a otra parte del codigo o mostrar un formulario...

Comment: Esperemos sea la respuesta q busca :)